# All other input data get clear when I i hit handleSubmit

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Hi i am working on a React application where there are four options.when a user select an option corresponding input element will be added to the wrapper.In the following code add operation works fine but remove operation is not working properly ,it is not removing the corresponding element.Another problem the values on the inputs fields not present when the component re-renders.so experts guide me how i can acheive removing the corresponding row when the remove button is clicked and the input values should not be reset when the component re-renders.

But when I submit the input it will appear my data perfectly and when i restart the page and just click into edit and hit submit with the defaultValue it just clear all the data and send back to my backend with `undefined` value like this: `[ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]`

Here is my full component:

```
const Agreement = (props) => {
  const { agreement, editable, teamData, teamId, fetchTeamData } = props;
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [showErrors, setShowErrors] = useState(false);
  const [errorsArr, setErrorsArr] = useState();

  const initialFormState = {
    rule_0: teamData.rules.rule_0,
    rule_1: teamData.rules.rule_1,
    rule_2: teamData.rules.rule_2,
    rule_3: teamData.rules.rule_3,
    creator: teamData.User.public_user_id,
  };

  const [updateTeamData, setUpdateTeamData] = useState(initialFormState);

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(teamData.rules);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    // Update state
    setUpdateTeamData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  // Add more input
  const addInputs = () => {
    setInputs([...inputs, { name: `rule_${inputs.length + 1}` }]);
  };

  // handle click event of the Remove button
  const removeInputs = (index) => {
    const list = [...inputs];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setInputs(list);
  };

  const clearInput = (dataName) => {
    setUpdateTeamData((prevState) => {
      delete prevState[dataName];
      return {
        ...prevState,
      };
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setEditing(false);
    // Send update request

    const res = await axios.put(`/api/v1/teams/team/${teamId}`, updateTeamData);

    // If no validation errors were found
    // Validation errors don't throw errors, it returns an array to display.
    if (res.data.validationErrors === undefined) {
      // Clear any errors
      setErrorsArr([]);
      // Hide the errors component
      setShowErrors(false);
      // Call update profiles on parent
      fetchTeamData();
    } else {
      // Set errors
      setErrorsArr(res.data.validationErrors.errors);
      // Show the errors component
      setShowErrors(true);
    }
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setEditing(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (agreement === "default") {
      setTitle(defaultTitle);
      setInputs(teamData.rules);
    } else {
      setTitle(agreement.title ?? "");
    }
  }, [agreement, teamData]);

  console.log("teamData.rules", teamData.rules);
  console.log("inputs", inputs);

  return (
    <div className="team-agreement-container">
      {!editing && (
        <>
          <h4 className="team-agreement-rules-title">{title}</h4>
          {editable && (
            <div className="team-agreement-rules">
              <EditOutlined
                className="team-agreement-rules-edit-icon"
                onClick={() => setEditing(true)}
              />
            </div>
          )}
          <p className="team-agreement-rules-description">{description}</p>
          {teamData.rules.map((rule, index) => (
            <div className="team-agreement-rule-item" key={`rule-${index}`}>
              {rule ? (
                <div>
                  <h4 className="team-agreement-rule-item-title">
                    {`Rule #${index + 1}`}
                  </h4>
                  <p className="team-agreement-rule-item-description">
                    - {rule}
                  </p>
                </div>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </div>
          ))}
        </>
      )}
      {/* Edit rules form */}
      {editing && (
        <div className="team-agreement-form">
          {showErrors && <ModalErrorHandler errorsArr={errorsArr} />}
          <h1>Rules</h1>
          {inputs.map((data, idx) => {
            return (
              <div className="agreement-form-grid" key={`${data}-${idx}`}>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="agreement-remove-button"
                  onClick={() => {
                    removeInputs(idx);
                    clearInput(`rule_${idx}`);
                  }}
                >
                  <Remove />
                </button>
                <input
                  name={`rule_${idx}`}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={teamData.rules[idx]}
                />
              </div>
            );
          })}
          {inputs.length < 4 && (
            <div className="team-agreement-add-rule">
              <button type="submit" onClick={addInputs}>
                <Add />
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
          <div className="div-button">
            <button className="save-button" onClick={handleSubmit}>
              Save
            </button>
            <button className="cancel-button" onClick={handleCancel}>
              Cancel
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Agreement;
```

How can I fix this error?

My thought is the problem is around `[inputs, setInputs]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input
  //..
  onChange={(event) => handleChange(event.target.value)}
  //..
/>
```

then in your "handleChange" function

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
const { name, value } = event;
//....
```

};

Comment: It 's not working. The data didn't send to backend